# How do I stack HTML tables with text in between?

Tags: html, css, html-table

How do I stack HTML tables with text in between? I am getting text displayed on the side of the table. What am I missing?

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WW3bh/30768/).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <p style="align: left;"> Table1 </p>
    <table style="background-color: #E0E0E0; font-family: helvetica; font-size: 15px; clear: left;" border="1" align="left">
        <tr>
            <th> No. </th>
            <th> Name </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> 1 </td>
            <td>Name1</td>
        </tr>   
    </table>
    <p style="align: left;"> Table2 </p>
    <table style="background-color: #E0E0E0; font-family: helvetica; font-size: 15px; clear: left;" border="1" align="left">
        <tr>
            <th> No. </th>
            <th> Color </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> 1 </td>
            <td> Color1 </td>
        </tr>   
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [Something like this?](http://jsfiddle.net/WW3bh/30770/) Your question isn't clear, please show us what your looking for.

Comment: If you remove all `style="align: left;"` and `align ="left"`, they automatically stack(?)

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek Yes. That was what I was looking for. Please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't CSS defined to push the second paragaph to it's own line, one way to do that is add `clear:both` in it's CSS:

```html
<p>Table1</p>
<table style="background-color:#E0E0E0; font-family: helvetica;font-size: 15px;clear: left;" border="1" align ="left">
<tr><th>No.</th><th>Name</th></tr>
<tr><td> 1 </td><td>Name1</td></tr>   
</table>
<p style="clear:both">Table2</p>
<table style="background-color:#E0E0E0; font-family: helvetica;font-size: 15px;clear: left;" border="1" align ="left">
<tr><th>No.</th><th>Color</th></tr>
<tr><td> 1 </td><td>Color1</td></tr>   
</table>
```

Or simple removing the `align` and `clear` that is causing this, HTML will do what you want by default:

```html
<p>Table1</p>
<table style="background-color:#E0E0E0; font-family: helvetica;font-size: 15px;" border="1" >
<tr><th>No.</th><th>Name</th></tr>
<tr><td> 1 </td><td>Name1</td></tr>   
</table>
<p>Table2</p>
<table style="background-color:#E0E0E0; font-family: helvetica;font-size: 15px;" border="1">
<tr><th>No.</th><th>Color</th></tr>
<tr><td> 1 </td><td>Color1</td></tr>   
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to wrap text+table in same wrapper element i.e `div` and apply style to it i.e.

```
div {
  float: left;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/WW3bh/30773/)

or

```
div {
  clear:both;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/WW3bh/30781/)